# How to make a custom 3d view cone that mixes orthographic and perspective cameras

Tags: unity, 3d, camera, mesh

I'm trying to make a camera that displays objects the same height no matter the distance, but still changes width relative to distance. Similar to having an orthographic view vertically and a perspective view horizontally. From what I've gathered the best way to go about this is to create a custom 3d mesh. Is that correct or is there a more efficient way? Thanks!

Edit:
Here are some images for visual reference.

This is a white cube against a yellow wall at medium distance.

[image]

This is the cube up close.
[image]

This is the cube further away.
[image]

The cube stays the same height no matter the distance, but its width changes relative to how close the camera is.

I've tried modelling what the view cone would look like for this FOV/perspective based on the form of the perspective and orthographic view cones in unity. As can be seen the height of the view cone is static, but the width increases with distance.
[image]

Does anyone know the best way to create this view system in unity?

Comment: Can you include some images (or even drawings) for visual reference?

Comment: Hey. I've updated the description with some visuals.

Answer (score 1):

the vertex shader way would be to divide the x/horizontal axis (screenspace) by the z/depth axis (screenspace) though i don't really know how unity works that much

Comment: wow i didn't think that would get an upvote